# Dúvida com join

Tags: banco-de-dados

Tenho a tabela `address` aonde dou o select:

```
SELECT street, number, city_id,town
FROM address
WHERE address_id = :address
```

E na tabela `city` tenho o `city_id` e tenho o link. Preciso pegar esse link no meu select. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/18246)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    street,
    number,
    city.city_id,
    town,
    link
FROM
    address
INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
WHERE
    address.id = : address
```

Comment: Obrigada, funcionou!

Comment: É nóis que voa.